# Read multiple fields from multiple lines into unique variables from Fortran file to Bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have a data file that goes like

```
value1    value2    value3    ...
value4    value5    value6    ...
...
```

I want to read all of them into different variables in a bash file. Line 1 fields goes into `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`, line 2 fields goes into `charlie`, `john`, `cena` etc. The variable names are unique and don't share a common word/sequential naming scheme. The values from the files are both numbers and words.

Is there an elegant way to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read` statements to read each line into a set of variables. You can use curly braces to group all the statements so they read from the same file stream.

```
{ 
    read alpha beta gamma ...
    read charlie john cena ...
    ... 
} < filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Will `read` know how to jump over the whitespaces between the columns in the Fortran file?

Comment: Yes, whitespace is the default delimiter between words that get assigned to each variable.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "fortran file". It's just a plain text file.